# Turn entire database into RESTful API

Tags: php, mysql, database, rest, laravel

I'm trying to convert MySQL database to a RESTful API in my Laravel APP. I came across this [package](https://github.com/project-open-data/db-to-api) in github.

I've tried it, and followed every instruction, and here are my settings:

```
$args = array(
            'name' => 'cacti',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => '****',
            'server' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 3306,
            'type' => 'mysql',
            'table_blacklist' => array(),
            'column_blacklist' => array()
);

register_db_api( 'dataset-name', $args );
```

---

This is what I have in `register_db()`:

```
function register_db( $name = 'cacti', $args = array() ) {

        $defaults = array(
            'name' => 'cacti',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => '****',
            'server' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 3306,
            'type' => 'mysql',
            'table_blacklist' => array(),
            'column_blacklist' => array(),
            'ttl' => $this->ttl
        );

        $args = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $args );
        $name = $this->slugify( $name );

        $this->dbs[$name] = (object) $args;

    }
```

I kept getting:

> Must select a database

I triple checked my database settings, and I used that same settings for MySQL Workbench and I can log-in and see my database fine.

What did I miss?

I'm open to any new suggestions that will help me turn my database into a RESTful API.

Comment: Do you have a database called `dataset-name` ?

Comment: No I don't. My database name is **cacti**. Should I change it to that ?

Comment: I see two functions  register_db_api and register_db , I think that mean the seem function !

Answer (score 1):

When using your example:

```
$args = array(
            'name' => 'cacti',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => '****',
            'server' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 3306,
            'type' => 'mysql',
            'table_blacklist' => array(),
            'column_blacklist' => array()
);

register_db_api( 'dataset-name', $args );
```

You will have to use the url:

```
/dataset-name/table-name
```

The `dataset-name` does not have to match the actual database name, like others are saying. This name is actually the data set name, which can be anything you want.

Side note; Please do not use this package as it is both horrible in code and seems to have no automated tests.

Comment: Ahh.. Okay. I got  it now. Thanks for shedding more lights on this ! :D

Comment: Hmm... do you have a favorite package that you don't mind sharing ?

Comment: @ihue why a package like that at all? It's very unlikely that all your API will do is receive data and save it to database as is.

Comment: I need the ability to query the data out of the database via some kind of HTTP. I don't know how else, I would do that.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu : `http://localhost:8080/api/v2/sql/users` should return me a list of users table.

Comment: @ihue Simply make a UsersController, set it's route in the `routes.php` file and at the `index` method, `return Users::all();`.

Comment: That will only work with users table, my goal is to turn my entire databases into an API.

Comment: @ihue that's what I'm telling you shouldn't do. You should at least have one controller per table.

Comment: I wrote a small [script](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api) that may do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it myself, within Laravel.

## #1 - route

```
Route::get('api/psql/{table_name}', 'ApiController@psql');
```

---

## #2 - controller

```
 public function psql($table_name){
    $object = DB::table($table_name)->get();
    return $object;
}
```

---

---

## #3 - call it

```
http://localhost:8888/api/psql/users
```

Result

```
[
{
"id": 2005,
"account_id": "2005",
"email": "test@b",
"fb_email": "",
"tw_email": "",
"created_at": "2016-08-09 11:19:30",
"updated_at": "2016-08-09 11:19:30",
"fb_access_token": "",
"fb_profile_id": "",
"fb_page_id": "",
"fb_username": "",
"auto_provisioning": null,
"service_plan": null
},
{
"id": 2004,
"account_id": "2004",
"email": "test@outlook.com2",
"fb_email": "",
"tw_email": "",
"created_at": "2016-08-08 11:39:50",
"updated_at": "2016-08-09 14:02:55",
"fb_access_token": "",
"fb_profile_id": "",
"fb_page_id": "",
"fb_username": "",
"auto_provisioning": "1",
"service_plan": "Blast"
}
]
```